# C3 Bar Graph x-axis labels are too congested

Tags: javascript, html, bar-chart, c3.js

I have created a Bar graph using C3 JS plugin, The graph is working fine but the problem is with the x-axis labels looks too congested like as shown below

[image]

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz0t10yb/)**

My Code is as given below

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: "#chart",
    data: {
        x : 'x',
        columns: [

['x', "2016-04-01","2016-04-08","2016-04-15","2016-04-22","2016-04-29","2016-05-06","2016-05-13","2016-05-20","2016-05-27","2016-06-03","2016-06-10","2016-06-17","2016-06-24","2016-07-09","2016-07-10","2016-07-11","2016-07-12","2016-07-13","2016-07-15","2016-07-16","2016-07-17","2016-07-18","2016-07-19","2016-07-20","2016-07-21","2016-07-22","2016-07-23","2016-07-24","2016-07-25","2016-07-26","2016-07-27","2016-07-28","2016-07-29","2016-07-30","2016-07-31","2016-08-01","2016-08-02","2016-08-03","2016-08-04","2016-08-05","2016-08-06","2016-08-07","2016-08-08","2016-08-09","2016-08-10","2016-08-11","2016-08-12","2016-08-13","2016-08-14","2016-08-15","2016-08-16","2016-08-17","2016-08-18","2016-08-19","2016-08-20","2016-08-21","2016-08-22","2016-08-23","2016-08-24","2016-08-25","2016-08-26","2016-08-27","2016-08-28","2016-08-29","2016-08-30","2016-08-31","2016-09-01","2016-09-02","2016-09-03","2016-09-04","2016-09-05","2016-09-06","2016-09-07","2016-09-08","2016-09-09","2016-09-10","2016-09-11","2016-09-12","2016-09-13","2016-09-14","2016-09-15","2016-09-16","2016-09-17","2016-09-18","2016-09-19","2016-09-20","2016-09-21","2016-09-22","2016-09-23","2016-09-24","2016-09-25","2016-09-26","2016-09-27","2016-09-28","2016-09-29","2016-09-30","2016-10-01","2016-10-02","2016-10-03","2016-10-04","2016-10-05","2016-10-06","2016-10-07","2016-10-08","2016-10-09","2016-10-10","2016-10-11","2016-10-12","2016-10-13","2016-10-14","2016-10-15","2016-10-16","2016-10-17","2016-10-18","2016-10-19","2016-10-20","2016-10-21","2016-10-22","2016-10-23","2016-10-24","2016-10-25","2016-10-26","2016-10-27","2016-10-28","2016-10-29","2016-10-30","2016-10-31","2016-11-01","2016-11-02","2016-11-03","2016-11-04","2016-11-09"], 
['pv1', 2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2696,2748,2748,2694,2694,2694,2694,2694,2694,2694,2668,2668,2668,2668,2576,2572,2572,3043,3084,3084,3084,3084,3084,3156,3521,3521,3550,3542,3542,3573,3580,3629,3579,3584,3542,2757,2791,2696,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3415,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3414,3369,3376,3371,3373,3371,3379,3363,3373,3347,3348,3382,3402,3410,3434,2579,2579,2369],
['pv2', 1750,1750,1750,1750,1825,1850,1975,2150,2375,2425,2475,2500,2500,2087,2087,2087,2087,2091,2087,1767,1767,1767,1633,1498,1498,1642,1637,1633,1609,1841,1713,1702,1862,1888,1888,1888,1949,1976,1977,2014,2014,2014,1946,1966,1973,2224,2252,2318,2318,2318,2327,2373,2513,2535,2543,2534,2539,2823,2849,2990,3142,3142,3108,2513,2687,2678,2856,2860,2861,2862,2866,2869,2870,2875,2874,2874,2874,2879,2885,2886,2883,2889,2896,2895,2899,2903,2909,2911,2913,2913,2913,2916,2922,2933,2937,2943,2942,2943,2947,1811,1826,1837,1840,1840,1841,1843,1511,1854,1853,1851,1852,1853,1849,1852,1874,1857,1883,1886,1888,1904,1903,1924,1947,2060,2068,2068,2082,1582,1344,836,839,788]
], 
        type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            tick: {
                rotate: -60,
                multiline: false
            },
            height: 130
        }

    }
});
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**What I did to solve it**

I have used timeseries type instead of category type, after that the label issue got resolved but the graph was been plottted with more white spaces for the month of march like as shown below

[image]

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz0t10yb/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use c3's tick count setting for this, so here we say 20 labels.

However there is an added gotcha in that ticks that now resolve to a fractional category value won't show - i.e. the 2nd equally spaced tick out of 20 may be the 2.6667th element in the x category axis - so you need to have a little format function that adjusts for this, otherwise you just get the end and start labels. (Or you could figure out a tick count that divides into your data count + 1 as a whole number.)

```
tick: {
   format: function (x) { 
      var cats = this.api.categories();
      return cats[Math.round(x)];
   },
   count: 20,
   rotate: -60,
   multiline: false
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fz0t10yb/7/

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution could be to use x-axis labels at required indexes only & leaving others blank.

```
['x', "2016-04-01","","","","2016-04-29","","","",...]
['pv1', 2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,...]
['pv2', 1750,1750,1750,1750,1825,1850,1975,2150,...]
```

You can position labels so that it would capture the date and at same time it looks good also.

Comment: How about the timeseries. Do u have any idea why that white space is coming

Comment: Probably because your data is not consistent. i.e. x-axis values are not equally spaced. Initially data is 7 days spaced & later is it on daily basis.

Comment: No idea about that :(